# jQuery toggle button text and Icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle both the icon and the button text on a button and each function works independently, but they will not work when run consecutively. Seems that the function to toggle the button text is removing my icon altogether.

```
<button type="button" id="toggle-list-details">
    <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i> 
    List View
</button>
```

```js
$("#toggle-list-details").click(function() {
    $(this).text(function(i, text){
        return text === " List View" ? " Details View" : " List View";
      });                                
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-list fa-th-list'); 
)};
```

Comment: wrap your button text in a span and then `$(this).find('span').innerHtml('button text');

Comment: yes when setting text of your button, you remove the <i> you need to be able to select the text only as Jacob Roberts suggested

Comment: As others have suggested using a `span` is the conventional way of doing this. If you don't want to add a new tag to wrap your text take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
```

`this` reffers to `<button type="button" id="toggle-list-details">`, so it replaces all inner content with plain text.

To avoid this, you can do smth like this:

```
<button type="button" id="toggle-list-details">
    <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i> 
    <span class="text">List View</span>
</button>

$("#toggle-list-details").click(function() {
    $(this).find('span').text(function(i, text){
        return text === " List View" ? " Details View" : " List View";
      });                                
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-list fa-th-list'); 
)};
```